# Flask query string second parameter returns null

Tags: python, flask, query-string

I'm trying to get 2 values from a query string in Flask, but for some reason that's incomprehensible to me, Flask's request object only manages to get hold of the first value.

Here's an example:

```
@app.route('/whatishappening')
def what():
    please = request.args.get('please')
    work = request.args.get('work')

    return jsonify({'strange': (please, work)})
```

A curl command:

```
curl -i http://localhost:5000/whatishappening?please=god&work=already
```

request.args('work') returns null:

```
{
  "strange": [
    "god",
    null
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` is used to fork a process. If you wrap the URL in quotes, you should see the expected output.

```
$ curl -i "http://0.0.0.0:5000/whatishappening?please=god&work=already"
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 48
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/3.4.2
Date: Sun, 07 Dec 2014 23:04:18 GMT

{
  "strange": [
    "god",
    "already"
  ]
}
```